# Converting a datetime.datetime item in a list of lists to strftime Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list that looks like the following:

```
[['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 30, 0, 39, 32), 'Log cribs holding approach fills are spreading (failing).  Hole in town approach at end of deck as a result.  Ballast walls independent of girders...could weld them.'], ['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 23, 12, 3), '3x1 WBC. Town side sill looks as if it shifted towards stream. Stringers overhang sill 2m. Stringers and sills cedar. 70cm of gravel surface. Both sills have been severely scoured, and actively moving. Recommend rebuilding WBC. Stream grade 13%']]
```

I want to convert the datetime.datetime items to strftime and am using the following code:

```
for i in list_of_lists:
  list_of_lists.append(i[1].strftime('%Y-%b-%d'))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

When I print type(i[1]) I get:

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

So my question is in my append statement why is it reading it as a string? Is there a way of doing what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are `append`ing to the list while iterating it... modifying the list while iterating it means you're gonna have a bad day.

Comment: At a certain point, `i[1] == '0'`.

Comment: You want `i[1] = i[1].strftime('%Y-%b-%d')` not `lst.append(...)`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending to the list is not the answer (and is a bad idea while iterating it):

```
for i in lst:
    print lst
    lst.append(i[1].strftime('%Y-%b-%d'))
```

Yields:

```
[['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 30, 0, 39, 32), '...'], ['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 23, 12, 3), '...']]
[['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 30, 0, 39, 32), '...'], ['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 23, 12, 3), '...'], '2017-Jun-30']
[['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 30, 0, 39, 32), '...'], ['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 23, 12, 3), '...'], '2017-Jun-30', '2017-Jun-29']
```

Notice all the way right it is appending new items to the list, instead of converting them, so it then tries to do the same on `'2017-Jun-30'` and fails.

Instead, we want to convert them:

```
for i in lst:
  print lst
  i[1] = i[1].strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
```

which yields:

```
[['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 30, 0, 39, 32), '...'], ['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 23, 12, 3), '...']]
[['Test', '2017-Jun-30', '...'], ['Test', datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 23, 12, 3), '...']]
[['Test', '2017-Jun-30', '...'], ['Test', '2017-Jun-29', '...']]
```